# Can't find the new <tr> append with Ajax using PHP MVC pattern

Tags: php, ajax

I try to develop the " Load More " using Ajax & PHP & MVC Pattern

but i get a problem that the new row added can't get it with ajax (it can't know him)

My ajax code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click','#More',function(){
        var id = $(".theID").last().val();
        alert(id);
        $.ajax({
            url:'/more',
            method: 'POST',
            data:{id:id},
            success:function(data){
                //if(data != ''){
                    $('#rank').append(data);
                /*}else{
                    $('#Load').remove();
                }*/
            }
        });
     });
 });
```

My PHP code in controller

```
$datas = User::loadMore($_POST['id']);
echo View::getTemplate('User/data.html',['datas'=>$datas]);
```

My HTML code

```
<tbody id='rank'>
    <tr>                
   <td>
      1 
   </td>

   <td>
  <img alt='' src='img/test.jpg'/>
   </td>
   <button class='theID' value="{{rank.ID}}" style='display: none'></button>
  </tr> 

  </tbody>

<button id='More' style=''>More</button>
```

data.html code

```
{% for key,data in datas %}
<tr>
        <td>
                {{key}} 
        </td>

  <button class='theID' value="{{data.ID}}" style='display: none'></button>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The ajax code work correctly but when I get the data the ID was always the first one.

Comment: Where is the `#rank` element? Where is the `#More` element?

Comment: @Phil I updated the post

Comment: Not sure if it will fix your problem, but you're missing the opening `<tr>` tag in your `tbody`. Also, your `button class='theID'` is outside of any `td`.

Comment: Where do you "get the data"? Is the problem that your AJAX call already uses the wrong parameter, or that the response is not as expected, or that you cannot add the correctly generated new row to the existing markup?

Comment: "My HTML code"...this is the code of `data.html`,or not?

Comment: @ADyson The data.html is just a new `<tr>` had the new infos, the problem is when I make `var_dump` in the first of controller it's work correctly

Comment: by that you mean that `$datas` is populated correctly? If so then, show us the `data.html` code. And also in `success:function(data){`...what is in `data` there?

Comment: @ADyson `data` in `success:function(data){` is the new `<tr>` that getting from the Action in controller (`data.html`). the problem exactly is when I get the new data he can't get the last ID from it, he always gets the ID in first line ( I make the data.html code )

Comment: " he can't get the last ID"...who can't? Code isn't a person - you mean there's some line of code trying to read the ID, or what? Please be specific and clear. Are you talking about this line: `var id = $(".theID").last().val();`?

Comment: btw why are you making hidden buttons to contain your IDs? You know about HTML hidden fields, that would be a more logical thing to create - unless sometimes the button becomes visible, perhaps?

Comment: @ADyson Sorry for my bad English I mean (it), yes this code `var id = $(".theID").last().val();` to get the last ID and about hidden button it's just to set the ID and get it with JavaScript

Comment: OK well you could use a hidden field for that, no need to make a button and then hide it. Anyway I just noticed your html is not valid - anything within a tr must also be within a td, you cannot out anything else directly within the td. I wonder if this is why jquery is having trouble finding the ID field, it's not in a valid location